# List of lines to quoted arguments in bash

Tags: bash

I have a command that returns a list of net interfaces surrounded by quotes:-

```
networksetup -listnetworkserviceorder | grep "Hardware Port" | grep -v "Wi-Fi" | sed 's#([^:]*:\ \([^,]*\),.*#\"\1\"#'
```

Now I need to turn that into the arguments for another command :-

```
networksetup -ordernetworkservices "Wi-Fi" <the other interfaces>.
```

I tried

```
services=`networksetup -listnetworkserviceorder | grep "Hardware Port" | grep -v "Wi-Fi" | sed 's#([^:]*:\ \([^,]*\),.*#\"\1\"#' | paste -sd " " -`
# set order after above
networksetup -ordernetworkservices Wi-Fi $services
```

but that's failing. It seems my quotes are being stripped off, but I can't figure out why.

```
echo $services
```

gives me

```
"Dell Universal Dock D6000" "USB 10/100/1000 LAN" "Bluetooth PAN" "Thunderbolt Bridge"
```

I've also tried the above with the variable surrounded by both single and double quotes.

The command will spit out to the shell :

```
"Dell Universal Dock D6000"
"USB 10/100/1000 LAN"
"Bluetooth PAN"
"Thunderbolt Bridge"
```

What I need in the end is:

```
networksetup -ordernetworkservices Wi-Fi "Dell Universal Dock D600" "USB 10/100/1000 LAN" "Bluetooth PAN" "Thunderbolt Bridge"
```

I know the answer is right in front of me but I'm missing it.

Comment: Try `"$services"`?

Comment: See: [**Bash FAQ**](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ), specifically [**Number 50**](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050) If I recall correctly. You should capture your interface names in an array and use that for your command line argument.

Comment: Within Bash FAQ 50, see *"5. I'm constructing a command based on information that is only known at run time*"

Comment: Still can't figure out a way of getting that list of lines into a list of arguments surrounded by double quotes so it's accepted as a list of words for the command. Even putting it in an array, it gets parsed into the array stripped of quotes.

Comment: Try replacing the double quotes in the variable by single quotes (with sed).  Then quote the variable with double quotes when you use it.

Comment: Tried that, Peter.

Comment: I've also now spent some time attempting to get the lines into a bash array but that's not working for me either.

Comment: Hard to test and experiment, since my (most?) system doesn't have **networksetup**. Can you write a mock function, and use that, to produce the output, your command produces, and use that in your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First: in the shell, you should think of quotes as things that go *around* data, not things that go *in* data. You're embedding quotes in your data, and expecting them to work as though they were around the data, and it just doesn't work that way. More specifically, the shell parses quotes (and escapes and a bunch of other things) before it substitutes variable values, so if you have a quote in a variable's value, by the time it gets substituted into the command line it's too late for it to have the intended effect.

So what do you do to maintain each port name as a separate item when they might contain spaces? In bash, you can store them in an array, and expand the array with `"${arrayname[@]}"` -- the combination of double-quotes and `[@]` makes bash treat each array element as a separate word, essentially as though each item were individually quoted.

So how do you get the output from `networksetup` into an array? Well, if you had bash version 4 you could use `readarray`, but macOS only comes with bash v3. You can still do it, it's just a little more work. You have a `read` loop read each line of output from `networksetup`, processed to remove everything except the service names (and *without* quotes added). But you can't have the loop be part of a pipeline, or it'll run in a subshell and the data will get lost when that exits, so you have to redirect the loop's input from a command substitution with `< <( )`. Something like this:

```
service_list=()
while read service; do
    service_list+=("$service")    # Note: double-quotes and parens are both needed
done < <(networksetup -listnetworkserviceorder | grep "Hardware Port" | grep -v "Wi-Fi" | sed 's#([^:]*:\ \([^,]*\),.*#\1#')

networksetup -ordernetworkservices Wi-Fi "${service_list[@]}"
```

BTW, for @userunknown and others without access to macOS trying to solve/test this, here's a sample output:

```
$ networksetup -listnetworkserviceorder
An asterisk (*) denotes that a network service is disabled.
(1) iPhone USB
(Hardware Port: iPhone USB, Device: en5)

(2) Ethernet
(Hardware Port: Ethernet, Device: en0)

(3) Wi-Fi
(Hardware Port: Wi-Fi, Device: en1)

(*) FireWire
(Hardware Port: FireWire, Device: fw0)

(4) Bluetooth PAN
(Hardware Port: Bluetooth PAN, Device: en4)

(5) Thunderbolt Bridge
(Hardware Port: Thunderbolt Bridge, Device: bridge0)
```

Answer (score 2):

Without such a networksetup program, it's hard to tell. But look:

```
mock () {
  echo '"Dell Universal Dock D6000"
"USB 10/100/1000 LAN"
"Bluetooth PAN"
"Thunderbolt Bridge"'
}

mock
"Dell Universal Dock D6000"
"USB 10/100/1000 LAN"
"Bluetooth PAN"
"Thunderbolt Bridge"

echo $(mock)
"Dell Universal Dock D6000" "USB 10/100/1000 LAN" "Bluetooth PAN" "Thunderbolt Bridge"

echo "$(mock)"
"Dell Universal Dock D6000"
"USB 10/100/1000 LAN"
"Bluetooth PAN"
"Thunderbolt Bridge"
```

and:

```
for s in $(echo "$(mock)"); do echo "<"$s">"; done 
<"Dell>
<Universal>
<Dock>
<D6000">
<"USB>
<10/100/1000>
<LAN">
<"Bluetooth>
<PAN">
<"Thunderbolt>
<Bridge">

for s in "$(echo "$(mock)")"; do echo "<"$s">"; done 
<"Dell Universal Dock D6000" "USB 10/100/1000 LAN" "Bluetooth PAN" "Thunderbolt Bridge">
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems you want to reorder network ports, so that `Wi-Fi` is in front of everything else.

You try to create a command as you would type it on the command line. Although, it is a question of putting the arguments in an order. So don't put the quotes around the network names, just let the arguments stand for themselves, e.g.

```
networksetup -listnetworkserviceorder | grep "Hardware Port" | grep -v "Wi-Fi" |
    sed 's#([^:]*:\ \([^,]*\),.*#\1#'
```

Now you can put them together with [`xargs`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/xargs.1.html)

```
networksetup -listnetworkserviceorder | grep "Hardware Port" | grep -v "Wi-Fi" |
    sed 's#([^:]*:\ \([^,]*\),.*#\1#' |
    xargs networksetup -ordernetworkservices Wi-Fi
```

But this doesn't work as expected, because the hardware ports have spaces inside (hence the perceived need for quotes). To fix this, you can separate the hardware ports by a NUL byte instead of a newline. To replace newlines with a NUL byte, use [`tr`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/tr.1.html)

```
networksetup -listnetworkserviceorder | grep "Hardware Port" | grep -v "Wi-Fi" |
    sed 's#([^:]*:\ \([^,]*\),.*#\1#' | tr -s '\n' '\0' |
    xargs -0 networksetup -ordernetworkservices Wi-Fi
```

Now xargs properly passes the arguments to networksetup.